# Check a CheckBox within a RecyclerView when it is loaded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I am creating a `RecyclerView` which has items. Each item has a `CheckBox`, `ImageButton` and a `TextView` as stated below:

```
public class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout item;
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
    ImageButton delete;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        item = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item_item);
        id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item_id);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item_name);
        delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item_delete);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_item_checkbox);
    }
}
```

I want the `checkbox` view to be checked only if a certain value in a column of a database is equal to `1`. If the value is `0`, it should not be checked. I have started off with the code below:

```
SQLiteDatabaseAdapter database = new SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(context);
    database.open();

    Cursor cursor = database.getAllItems(table);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (cursor.getInt(2) == 0) {
                viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }

            else {
                viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    database.close();
```

This code works but it checks the first row in the database and if the `checked` column is `1`, it changes **every** single `CheckBox` to be checked. I only want the `CheckBox` associated with one particular row to be checked, not every single one. How do I exactly do that?

Comment: Use a hashmap to hold the data from the databse and notify the recyclerview adapater. At the onBIndView() of the adapter check the checkbox according to the data in the hashmap.

Comment: @Malith Lakshan I will try using a hashmap.

Comment: Please show which class and method contains the code snippet.

Comment: I have figure it out now. I wasn't too sure on the entire `HashMap<>` thing. All of the code is above. It's in the `onBindViewHolder` function which is the second part of the code. I am more than happy to accept any more advice.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to show the containing class and method. This will help make your question more clear. As for an answer, I'll be posting something shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create a `HashMap<>` and link the IDs and the checked states. Then, you can reference from the `HashMap<>` and get the checked states.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder` function, you can use the following to check you `CheckBox`:

```
if (hashMap.get(position) == 0) {
    // not checked
}

else {
    // checked
}
```

Make sure you add the IDs and checked states from your SQLite database.

Comment: Thankyou, I have been waiting for an answer. I wasn't sure on how to do this. Now I can figure out the database part for myself.

Comment: As a small suggestion, a`List` or array might be more appropriate than a `HashMap` since the keys are `Integer`s. (Of course, it appears that the point is moot for the OP. I just thought I'd post it here for future posterity.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Definitely! I find the `HashMap<>` a better if you only want one particular value by retrieving it with another value but a `List<>` is also a good option!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are iterating through every row in the cursor. Instead, you need to go to the row for the current `position` by calling [`cursor.moveToPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition(int)).

In pseudocode, the steps you should follow are

1. Open the database.
2. Get the cursor.
3. Move the cursor to the correct row.
4. Retrieve the value from the cursor.
5. Set the `Checkbox` to the correct state.
6. Close the cursor.

I leave the details as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Personally, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dynamix No. The only `if` statement should be the one that checks the value from the correct row in the database.

Comment: Alright then. Just to let you know, I dropped this project but I will use your feedback for my new project. So thankyou, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Razor Thanks for the vote of confidence. Of course, a data structure solution has its place if there are any efficiency issues.